# Why use mocha gem if Minitest have stub and Mocks?

Tags: mocking, minitest, stub

I see Minitest provides Mock and stubbing. Then why does somebody use mocha gem for mocking and stubbing? Are Minitest stub and mocks have limitation. If yes then can somebody explain this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question and am in the quest of finding the answer. "The art of unit testing", the book, by Roy Osherove could help. I'm reading it and have finding some insights.

I would recommend it as a reference for a evaluating framework. Mocha is an isolation framework. Hence, for examples, Roy points out a good isolation framework provides 'future-proofing'. So it should provides "recursive fakes".

Translating it to Rspec, it is 'as_null_object' where in Mocha, it is 'stub_everything'. Minitest stub doesn't have this feature.

The question is, are you tolerate failing tests caused by indirect production code changes? I do. So instead of letting the test pass silently, I love to see them fail and scream for another layer of indirection.

Let me illustrate.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class LibraryTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_update_publisher__add_a_book__library_titles_include_the_new_title
    new_title = "the art of unit testing"
    library = Library.new

    Book.stub(:newest_book, {title: new_title}) do
      library.add_book Book.newest_book
    end

    assert_includes library.titles, new_title
  end
end

class Library
  attr_reader :titles, :authors
  def initialize
    @titles = []
    @authors = []
  end

  def add_book book
    titles << book[:title]
    # authors << book[:author][:first_name]
  end
end

class Book
  def self.newest_book
  end
end
```

Introducing a change, the library also wants to update its authors list. The test will has an error. Not a fail.

I like this because it hints that I'm doing something evil here.

I should introduce another level of indirection by extracting 2 methods "add_new_title" and "add_new_author". With that, this test logic will test 'add_new_title" function and we can stub out 'add_new_author' function easily. I believe this is a better design for the 'add_book' function.

I should not fix the test by adding more author information to the newest_book stub, which is irrelevant to the current test.